# Drush 8.1.10 via composer only partially working with D8.3

Tags: drush

Ubuntu 16.04
localhost
Drush 8.1.10 installed via composer as per the recommended route.
Drupal 8.3

Drush runs and completes some tasks.
 eg

*drush status*

> PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php
>   PHP configuration      :  /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
>   PHP OS                 :  Linux
>   Drush script           :  /home/rich/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
>   Drush version          :  8.1.10
>   Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
>   Drush configuration    :
>   Drush alias files      :

However when I try other commands I get errors

eg

*drush up*

> Command pm-update needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will
>   need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run
>   this command.                              [error] The drush command
>   'up' could not be executed.

and

*drush rebuild*

> Command cache-rebuild needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will
>   need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run
>   this command.                          [error] Command cache-rebuild
>   requires Drupal core version 8+ to run.
>   [error] The drush command 'rebuild' could not be executed.

Which is very odd as I am using D8.3 as confirmed via 'Status report'.

I have tried

*composer install*

> Loading composer repositories with package information Installing
>   dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file Nothing to install
>   or update Generating autoload files

So all looks good there.

*drush cc --root=http://localhost/drupal8-test1/*

> Enter a number to choose which cache to clear.
>   [0]  :  Cancel
>   [1]  :  drush

Drush does not find my install - which is installed and running fine

My settings.php

> $databases['default']['default'] = array (
>   'database' => 'drupal8-test1',
>   'username' => '*',
>
>   'password' => '*',
>   'prefix' => '',
>   'host' => '127.0.0.1',
>   'port' => '3306',
>   'namespace' => 'Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql',
>   'driver' => 'mysql', );

PATH in bash.rc

> export PATH=$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH export
>   PATH=/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH

Seems correct to me ...?

I have tried Forcing 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

I am running drush from drupal root directory.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions as to where to go next with this.
:)

Comment: Looks like Drush isn't able to connect to your database. Did you install the php-mysql package on your server?

Comment: Yes, I agree that seems to be the case - can't connect/find database. I thought I had already added that package ... anyway, I hadn't and I have now - but things are unchanged. Same errors returned.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are running Drush from the right directory? The output from `drush status` indicates that you are outside the Drupal directory. Could run `drush status` from the `sites` directory?

Comment: I am in the drupal root.
Runs the same in 'sites';

> sites$ > drush status  
> PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php                        
> PHP configuration      :  /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini                 
> PHP OS                 :  Linux                                    
> Drush script           :  /home/rich/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php  
> Drush version          :  8.1.10                                   
> Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                     
> Drush configuration    :                                           
> Drush alias files      :

Comment: Solved by adding "--root=/full/path/to/your/webroot" to the drush command. Thanks all :)